# nginx proxy_pass with upstream not working and gives a 404 error

Tags: nginx, iis, url-rewriting, rate-limiting

I have set up IIS with NGINX in the following manner:

> public_facing_IIS  --> NGINX[rate limiting]  --> internal_IIS

Users hit the public website url which forwards the request to NGINX which then forwards it to an internal IIS server. The reason for this chain is that I need to limit hits from NGINX to internal_IIS to a particular number-I don't want rate limiting at the public url end. In doing so when setting up an upstream with proxy pass I get a 404 error.

So this works for any link on the public facing IIS web site, but once I get into the path /Billing/ I get a 404 error

```
http{

    upstream myupstream {
            server internal.IISwebsite:80;
    }


  server {
        listen       81;
        server_name  internal.nginx;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://internal.IISwebsite;
        }

        location /Billing/ {
            limit_req zone=mylimit burst=20;

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://myupstream/;
        }
   }
```

}

I tried this even with by-passing the external_IIS url and calling the internal.nginx:81 directly. It all works well for every other url on http://internal.nginx:81. The minute I hit http://internal.nginx:81/Billing/ is when I get a http 404 error.

Comment: Check what kind of 404 you get, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 You also need to verify the bindings of the site on upstream server, or IIS won't be able to route the request to that site.

Comment: I couldnt see anything on that link that matched what I saw in the logs. Here below is the log file line in question:

Comment: `127.0.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2019:17:03:54 -0600] "GET /Billing/Index.aspx?q__=9g+D9urSlVgGj8K4To1cWcfV4IUvdjR3 HTTP/1.1" 404 3527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: The bindings on the upstream server are Type= http, IP address= All Unassigned, Port=80, Host name= internal.IISwebsite